# How to validate digits (including floats) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently i'm using this reg exp:

```
var valid = (value.match(/^\d+$/));
```

But for digits like '0.40', or '2.43' this doesn't work. How can I change that reg exp above to match floats as well?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var valid = (value.match(/^-?\d*(\.\d+)?$/));
```

Comment: My bad.  The corrected entry should address that and the situation where there are no numbers before the decimal point.  I'm assuming that there is a reason there is a preference to regex for this question (rather than using isNaN) such as tying it to some validation framework.

Comment: This also matches '' (empty string) and '-' (single dash).

Comment: this wrong regex mark non-valid for example these valid numbers:
+42
42.
42e42

Answer (score 63):

You don't need regex for this! [**`isNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Functions/IsNaN_Function) will cast thine value to `Number`:

```
var valid = !isNaN(value);
```

Eg:

```
!isNaN('0'); // true
!isNaN('34.56'); // true
!isNaN('.34'); // true
!isNaN('-34'); // true
!isNaN('foo'); // false
!isNaN('08'); // true
```

**Reluctant Edit** (thanks CMS):

Blasted type coercion, `!isNaN('')`, `!isNaN(' ')`, `!isNaN('\n\t')`, etc are all `true`!

Whitespace test + `isNaN` FTW:

```
var valid = !/^\s*$/.test(value) && !isNaN(value);
```

Yuck.

Comment: It's also funny because the accepted answer doesn't accept negative numbers :)

Comment: Nor does the accepted answer accept numbers such as `.42` or `37.`.

Comment: curse you JavaScript! "[tab][space][tab]" is **Not a Number** in my book! :-P

Comment: Less yucky? 
var valid = !isNaN(value.trim())

Answer (score 28):

Continuing with the [@Crescent Fresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830534/how-to-validate-digits-including-floats-in-javascript/1830547#1830547) approach, some time ago, I had to do number validation, but I needed to verify if a variable contained a number without knowing its type, it could be a `String` containing a numeric value as in this case, (I had to consider also exponential notation, etc.), a `Number` object, basically anything I couldn't make any type assumption.

And I had to take care about implicit type conversion, for example as I pointed to @Crescent, `isNaN` wasn't enough for my case:

```
// string values
!isNaN(' ') == true;
!isNaN('\t\t') == true;
!isNaN('') == true;

// boolean values
!isNaN(true) == true;
!isNaN(false) == true;

// etc..
```

I ended up writing a set of **30+** *unit tests* that you can find and run [here](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/35146/js/tests/isNumber.html), and the following function, is the one that passes all my tests:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: FTW! Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric You need to add this answer there. The accepted answer fails outright on whitespace strings.

Comment: @Crescent: LOL, actually it fails 10 of my tests hehe, I'll add it there in a minute...

Comment: @CMS: it's funny, Joel just updated his answer recently to account for it giving false positives on `''` (empty string). Really really nice test suite btw.

Comment: @Crescent: Thanks, the QUnit testrunner is really flexible. Added my answer, but I think it may remain buried on bottom....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844

Comment: Answers like this make me wish I could give more than +1. Anything backed up with that many tests deserves at least 2 :)

Comment: `jQuery.isNumeric` also passes all your tests.

Comment: This matches "00.0" and does not allow spaces between the sign (+-) and the value as in "+ 1".

Answer (score 8):

Here's my RegExp version.

```
var n = /^[+-]?((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?))$/;
```

**Match**

```
n.test('3');
n.test('3.0');
n.test('0.3');
n.test('.3');
n.test('+3');
n.test('+3.0');
n.test('+0.3');
n.test('+.3');
n.test('-3');
n.test('-3.0');
n.test('-0.3');
n.test('-.3');
```

**Don't match**

```
n.test('');
n.test('+');
n.test('-');
```

Comment: This is also not matching valid floats with exponential scientific notation like `1E-6` (0.000001) or `1E6` (1000000).

Comment: This doesn't capture a trailing decimal. eg. `3.`.



To capture that I have: `/^[+-]?((\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\d+\.))$/`

Answer (score 1):

You can try my solution: `/^-?\d+(\.?\d+)?$/.test(text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = (value.match(/^[\d.]+$/));
```

Comment: is it valid to have "1.1.1...1" , your expression is like "one to infinite  digit or dot".. I guess that's not a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = value.match(/\d+?\.\d+/);
```

Comment: Will not match `-2.4`, will match `23&56`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
/[\+]?([\-]?([0-9]{1,})?[\.]?[0-9]{1,})/
```

Comment: This matches "00.0" which is not a valid floating point. The regEx does not consume the trailling decimal as in "1.". It does not allow spaces between the sign (+-) and the value as in "+ 1".

Answer (score 0):

Here is validation without any regular expressions, using the "validity" property of the  element itself:

```
var valid = input_element.validity.valid;
```

Comment: -1? I thought it's obvious, especially there is many lines of code above which also does not require any comments. Topic itself describes what this code are doing. It validate the correctness of the input for some <input> element. Without any regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that accepts and captures all & only valid non-negative floats (but it doesn't handle exponents):

```
((?:\d+\.\d*)|(?:\d*\.?\d+))
```

Accepts 1, 1.0, 1., 0.1, .1 but not "." nor anything with more than one "."

See sample at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/t7eikU/1