# regular expression for finding decimal/float numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, decimal

i need a regular expression for decimal/float numbers like 12    12.2 1236.32 123.333 and +12.00 or -12.00  or ...123.123...  for using in javascript and jQuery.
Thank you.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Optionally match a + or - at the beginning, followed by one or more decimal digits, optional followed by a decimal point and one or more decimal digits util the end of the string:

```
/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

[**RegexPal**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2b-%5D?%5Cd%2b%28%5C.%5Cd%2b%29?$%0A&input=All%20these%20match:%0A%0A12%0A12.2%0A1236.32%0A123.333%0A%2b12.00%0A-12.00%0A123.123%0A0%0A%0AThese%20don%27t:%0A%0A127.0.0.1%0A$499.99%0A.5%0A)

Comment: Shouldn't the minus sign in `[+-]` be escaped like `[+\-]`?

Comment: @jfriend00 No, it doesn't need to be. It's not possible for it to be a range since it's the last character in the class, so it is a literal minus sign. Just try this in your console: `/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test('-1')`

Comment: @jfriend00 If the minus sign is the first or last character in a character class it specifies a minus sign literally. So in this case all of `[+-]`, `[-+]`, `[+\-]`, and `[\-+]` are equivalent.

Comment: @James It works for `0.99`. If you want to allow it to start with a decimal, change the first `\d+` to `\d*`.

Comment: That looks correct to me, but if you want to disallow redundant leading 0's you could use `(\d|[1-9]\d*)` before the decimal point.

Comment: What about e-notation? `.5e-3` is perfectly valid in JS.

Comment: @AralRoca There is no indication from the OP that they want it to work with `e`.

Comment: @JoshWang that was my complaint too. It accepts leading `0` on numbers greater than 1. Other answers accept a trailing `.` on numbers with no fractional part. I came up with https://stackoverflow.com/a/53000526 to address both.

Comment: What if I need to catch numbers like 1,000,000.45?

Comment: It returns `true` for `01`, but 01 is not a valuable number. I think it should be `/^[+-]?(0|[1-9]+[0-9]?)?(\.\d+)?$/`.

Answer (score 18):

The right expression should be as followed:

```
[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+
```

this apply for:

```
+1
+1.
+.1
+0.1
1
1.
.1
0.1
```

Here is Python example:

```
import re
#print if found
print(bool(re.search(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', '1.0')))
#print result
print(re.search(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', '1.0').group(0))
```

Output:

```
True
1.0
```

If you are using mac, you can test on command line:

```
python -c "import re; print(bool(re.search(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', '1.0')))"

python -c "import re; print(re.search(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', '1.0').group(0))"
```

Comment: This is better answer because I can put mesires like 9.5mm or 9.5in etc. Thanks for this +1

Comment: Does not seem to cover these cases: 23..8789  or 4587.387.987.
This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30461355/1783439

Answer (score 5):

You can check for text validation and also only one decimal point validation using isNaN

```
var val = $('#textbox').val();
var floatValues =  /[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/;
 if (val.match(floatValues) && !isNaN(val)) {
  // your function
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone new:

I made a RegExp for the E scientific notation *(matching the whole string)*.

```js
const floatR = /^[+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/;

floatR.test("-2.3E23"); //=> true
floatR.test("-2.E");    //=> false
floatR.test("  2  ");   //=> false
```

If you prefer to use [Unicode numbers](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), you could replace all `[0-9]` by `\d` in the RegExp.
And possibly add the Unicode flag `u` at the end of the RegExp.

For a better understanding of the pattern see [https://regexper.com/](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%5B%2B-%5D%3F%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%7C%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%28%3F%3A%5BeE%5D%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%29%24%2F).
And for making RegExp, I can suggest https://regex101.com/.

EDIT: found another site for viewing RegExp in color: [https://jex.im/regulex/](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5B%2B-%5D%3F(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F%7C%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B)(%3F%3A%5BeE%5D%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F)%24).

EDIT 2: although op asks for RegExp specifically you can check a string in JS directly:

```js
/**
 * ## Parse {@linkcode str} to number
 * @param {string} str - the string to parse
 * @returns {number | null} the parsed number or `null` if not-a-number
 */
const parseNum = str => Number.isNaN(str = Number(str)) ? null : str;

parseNum("123.12345678E+3") ?? 1; //=> 123123.45678
parseNum("80F") ?? 1;             //=> 1
```

Converting the string to a number (or `NaN`) with `Number()`
then checking if it is NOT `NaN` with `!Number.isNaN()`

EDIT 3: I found another cool site: see [this regexp on `debuggex.com`](https://www.debuggex.com/r/v-rDrUU9uCw1Q4zu).

EDIT 4: If you want to exclude leading/trailing 0s use the following

```js
// Exclude leading but not trailing 0s
const floatR_L = /^[+-]?(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][+-]?[1-9][0-9]*)?$/;

// Exclude leading and trailing 0s
const floatR_LT = /^[+-]?(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?|\.[0-9]*[1-9])(?:[eE][+-]?[1-9][0-9]*)?$/;
```

Also, in JavaScript, numbers can include underscores as numeric separators, so for completeness's sake, this should match any valid JS number:

```js
// Allow _ as separator, leading/trailing dot and 0s, and test for prefix 0b (binary), 0o (octal), and 0x (hexadecimal)
const numR = /^[+-]?(?:0[bB][01](?:_?[01]+)*|0[oO][0-7](?:_?[0-7]+)*|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F](?:_?[0-9a-fA-F]+)*|(?:[0-9](?:_?[0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[0-9](?:_?[0-9]+)*)?)?|\.[0-9](?:_?[0-9]+)*)(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9](?:_?[0-9]+)*)?)$/;

numR.test("007.123e+0_1"); //=> true
numR.test("-0xAbc");       //=> true
numR.test("+0x00F");       //=> true
numR.test("0b0010_1010");  //=> true
numR.test("2.");           //=> true
numR.test(".2");           //=> true
numR.test("00.");          //=> true
numR.test("  2  ");        //=> false
numR.test("2_");           //=> false
numR.test("2._2");         //=> false
```

Note: Some linters don't allow leading 0s in JS files because they're treated as octal literals with missing `0o` prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

*This is an old post but it was the top search result for "regular expression for floating point" or something like that and doesn't quite answer _my_ question.  Since I worked it out I will share my result so the next person who comes across this thread doesn't have to work it out for themselves.*

All of the answers thus far accept a leading `0` on numbers with two (or more) digits on the left of the decimal point (e.g. `0123` instead of just `123`)  This isn't really valid and in some contexts is used to indicate the number is in octal (base-8) rather than the regular decimal (base-10) format.

Also these expressions accept a decimal with no leading zero (`.14` instead of `0.14`) or without a trailing fractional part (`3.` instead of `3.0`). That is valid in some programing contexts (including JavaScript) but I want to disallow them (because for my purposes those are more likely to be an error than intentional).

Ignoring "scientific notation" like `1.234E7`, here is an expression that meets my criteria:

`/^((-)?(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?)$/`

or if you really want to accept a leading `+`, then:

`/^((\+|-)?(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?)$/`

I believe that regular expression will perform a strict test for the typical integer or decimal-style floating point number.

When matched:

- `$1` contains the full number that matched
- `$2` contains the (possibly empty) leading sign (+/-)
- `$3` contains the value to the left of the decimal point
- `$5` contains the value to the right of the decimal point, including the leading `.`

By "strict" I mean that the number must be the only thing in the string you are testing.

If you want to extract just the float value out of a string that contains other content use this expression:

`/((\b|\+|-)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]+)?)\b/`

Which will find `-3.14` in `"negative pi is approximately -3.14."` or in `"(-3.14)"` etc.

The numbered groups have the same meaning as above (except that `$2` is now an empty string (`""`) when there is no leading sign, rather than `null`).

But be aware that it will also try to extract whatever numbers it can find. E.g., it will extract `127.0` from `127.0.0.1`.

If you want something more sophisticated than that then I think you might want to look at lexical analysis instead of regular expressions.  I'm guessing one could create a look-ahead-based expression that would recognize that `"Pi is 3.14."` contains a floating point number but  `Home is 127.0.0.1.` does not, but it would be complex at best.  If your pattern depends on the characters that come after it in non-trivial ways you're starting to venture outside of regular expressions' sweet-spot.

Answer (score 3):

Paulpro and lbsweek answers led me to this:

```
re=/^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+$/;
>> /^[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+$/

re.exec("1")
>> Array [ "1" ]

re.exec("1.5")
>> Array [ "1.5" ]

re.exec("-1")
>> Array [ "-1" ]

re.exec("-1.5")
>> Array [ "-1.5" ]

re.exec(".5")
>> Array [ ".5" ]

re.exec("")
>> null

re.exec("qsdq")
>> null
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my js method , handling 0s at the head of string**

1- **^0[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$** : will find numbers starting with 0 and followed by numbers bigger than zero before the decimal seperator , mainly ".". I put this to distinguish strings containing numbers , for example, "0.111" from "01.111".

2- **([1-9]{1}[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)** : if there is string starting with 0 then the part which is bigger than 0 will be taken into account. parentheses are used here because I wanted to capture only parts conforming to regex.

3- **([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)**: to capture only the decimal part of the string.

In Javascript , st.match(regex), will return array in which  first element contains conformed part. I used this method in the input element's onChange event , by this if the user enters something that violates the regex than violating part is not shown in element's value at all but if there is a part that conforms to regex , then it stays in the element's value.

```
const floatRegexCheck = (st) => {
    const regx1 = new RegExp("^0[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$"); // for finding numbers starting with 0
    let regx2 = new RegExp("([1-9]{1}[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)"); //if regx1 matches then this will remove 0s at the head. 
    if (!st.match(regx1)) { 
        regx2 = new RegExp("([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)"); //if number does not contain 0 at the head of string then standard decimal formatting takes place
    }
    st = st.match(regx2);
    if (st?.length > 0) {
        st = st[0];
    }
    return st;
}
```

Comment: If you comment on the code to explain the inner workings you will likely get more votes and improve the experience for those with little knowledge of regex.

Comment: Thank you @Jairus for your feedback , I made some modifications in the answer,

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work with `e`, use this expression:

```
[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

Here is a JavaScript example:

```js
var re = /^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/;

console.log(re.test('1'));
console.log(re.test('1.5'));
console.log(re.test('-1'));
console.log(re.test('-1.5'));
console.log(re.test('1E-100'));
console.log(re.test('1E+100'));
console.log(re.test('.5'));
console.log(re.test('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more rigorous answer

```
^[+-]?0(?![0-9]).[0-9]*(?![.])$|^[+-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]*.[0-9]*$|^[+-]?.[0-9]+$
```

The following values will match (+- sign are also work)

```
.11234
0.1143424
11.21
1.
```

The following values will not match

```
00.1
1.0.00
12.2350.0.0.0.0.
.
....
```

**How it works**

The (?! ***regex***) means NOT operation

let's break down the regex by | operator which is same as logical OR operator

```
^[+-]?0(?![0-9]).[0-9]*(?![.])$
```

This regex is to check the value starts from 0

First Check + and - sign with 0 or 1 time `^[+-]`

Then check if it has leading zero `0`

If it has,then the value next to it must not be zero because we don't want to see 00.123 `(?![0-9])`

Then check the dot exactly one time and check the fraction part with unlimited times of digits `.[0-9]*`

Last, if it has a dot follow by fraction part, we discard it.`(?![.])$`

**Now see the second part**

```
^[+-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]*.[0-9]*$
```

`^[+-]?` same as above

If it starts from non zero, match the first digit exactly one time and unlimited time follow by it `[1-9]{1}[0-9]*` e.g. 12.3 , 1.2, 105.6

Match the dot one time and unlimited digit follow it `.[0-9]*$`

**Now see the third part**

```
^[+-]?.{1}[0-9]+$
```

This will check the value starts from . e.g. .12, .34565

`^[+-]?` same as above

Match dot one time and one or more digits follow by it `.[0-9]+$`