# Scraping a float value from the DOM not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a follow up of this question: [Scraping a float value from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065506/scraping-a-float-value-from-the-dom)

I'd like to take a number, have a new number created from that number displayed next to it, and have the original number crossed out.

HTML:

```
<span class="PageText_L483n">$8.00</span>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
       var price = parseFloat($('.PageText_L483n').text().substr(1));
       var discount = price * 0.2;
       var newPrice = price - discount;
       var newText = '<div>$' + price + '</div> $' + newPrice;
       $('.PageText_L483n').html(newText);
       $('.PageText_L483n div').css("text-decoration", "line-through");

});
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/GfBjC/

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but I assume the problem is when I try to assign the price variable. I've tried simplifying that line by removing parseFloat, text, and substring individually, but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it works. You just didn't have jQuery included in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbChJ/

Comment: include jQuery. I would make it a habit to check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: From the JSFiddle, it looks like you're trying to use the `$` function, which is not a browser defined function but something defined by jQuery. If I include jQuery in the fiddle, that seems to fix the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/GfBjC/2/. Is that the only issue?

Comment: Your fiddle needs jQuery to run. Add it in the dropdown at the top left.

Comment: It works - you didn't load the jQuery library.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is with this.  When I look at your jsFiddle, I don't see jquery selected.  when I selected the latest version (in the framework dropdown on the left) the code seems to work.

Comment: Wow.. did this question really need 6 comments and 3 answers all saying the same thing?

Comment: just in case it were not clear

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing script reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your fiddle. It's the first dropdown on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your fiddle, and it appears there was no library selected. If the jQuery library is included, it seems to be just fine... save for the lack of formatting. That can be fixed a la...

```
price = price.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works - you didn't load the jQuery library.