# how to use positive and negative look ahead for multiple terms in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'text':['inJECTable 1234 Eprex DOSE 4000 units on NONd',
                           'department 6789 DOSE 8000 units on DIALYSIS days  -  IV Interm',
                           'inJECTable 4321 Eprex DOSE - 3 times/wk on NONdialysis day',
                           'insulin MixTARD  30/70 - inJECTable 46 units',
                           'insulin ISOPHANE -- InsulaTARD  Vial -  inJECTable 56 units  SC SubCutaneous',
                           '1-alfacalcidol DOSE 1 mcg  - 3 times a week  -  IV Intermittent',
                           'jevity liquid - FEEDS PO  Jevity  -  237 mL  -  1 times per day',
                           '1-alfacalcidol DOSE 1 mcg  - 3 times per week  -  IV Intermittent',
                           '1-supported DOSE 1 mcg  - 1 time/day  -  IV Intermittent',
                           '1-testpackage DOSE 1 mcg  - 1 time a day  -  IV Intermittent']})
```

I would like to remove the words/strings which follow patterns such as `46 units`, `3 times a week`, `3 times per week`, `1 time/day` etc.

I was reading about positive and negative look ahead and behind.

So, was trying something like below

```
[^([0-9\s]*(?=units))]  #to remove terms like `46 units` from the string
[^[0-9\s]*(?=times)(times a day)] # don't know how to make this work for all time variants
```

time variants ex: `3 times a day`, `3 time/wk`, `3 times per day`, `3 times a month`, `3 times/month` etc.

Basically, I expect my output to be something like below (remove terms like xx units, xx time a day, xx times per week, xx time/day, xx time/wk, xx time/week, xx times per week, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider a pattern like

```
\s*\d+\s*(?:units?|times?(?:\s+(?:a|per)\s+|\s*/\s*)(?:d(?:ay)?|w(?:ee)?k|month|y(?:ea)?r?))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3Kpwv/2)

**NOTE**: the `\d+` matches one or more digits. If you need to match any number, please consider using other patterns for a number in the format you expect, see [regular expression for finding decimal/float numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256061/regular-expression-for-finding-decimal-float-numbers), for example.

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:units?|times?(?:\s+(?:a|per)\s+|\s*/\s*)(?:d(?:ay)?|w(?:ee)?k|month|y(?:ea)?r?))` - a non-capturing group matching:

  - `units?` - `unit` or `units`
  - `|` - or
  - `times?` - `time` or `times`
  - `(?:\s+(?:a|per)\s+|\s*/\s*)` - `a` or `per` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces, or `/` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:d(?:ay)?|w(?:ee)?k|month|y(?:ea)?r?)` - `d` or `day`, or `wk` or `week`, or `month`, or `y`/`yea`/`yr`

If you need to match whole words only, use word boundaries, `\b`:

```
\s*\b\d+\s*(?:units?|times?(?:\s+(?:a|per)\s+|\s*/\s*)(?:d(?:ay)?|w(?:ee)?k|month|y(?:ea)?r?))\b
```

In Pandas, use

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'\s*\b\d+\s*(?:units?|times?(?:\s+(?:a|per)\s+|\s*/\s*)(?:d(?:ay)?|w(?:ee)?k|month|y(?:ea)?r?))\b', '')
```