# Find Regex for `1.5×10^9` & `4.75×10^9` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to find a Regex for `1.5×10^9`. Another value I have is `4.75×10^9`

I have been able to make it work for `1.5×10^9` using `/(\d.\d)×10\^(\d)/` but that doesn't work for `4.75×10^9`.

Especially the first group is of decimal numbers & I'm not able to put [Regex for decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256061/regular-expression-for-finding-decimal-float-numbers) inside the first parenthesis `()`.

How do I do it?

I want only 2 values: the first decimal value & the one after caret `^`

Comment: Just replace `\d` with `\d+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Wiktor Stribizew's suggestion in the comments below:

```js
/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)×10\^(\d+)/ // matches 1.5×10^9 & 4.75×10^9
```

This works for my current use case but a more robust solution for decimal places can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256061/regular-expression-for-finding-decimal-float-numbers)

Comment: You have to escape the dot `\.` as it has a special meaning in regex.

Comment: Also, you need to use `+` with all `\d`, and probably allow integers as well by adding an optional group, `/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)×10\^(\d+)/`

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, I think your code looks perfect for my use case. I hadn't considered 2-digit numbers after the ^ sign. Good point on supporting integers as well.